# PyCharm SSH Terminal split

Tags: python, pycharm

I ran over following problem:

**If I try to split the ssh terminal in pycharm it just opens a local powershell instead of a second remote shell. Is this normal? Do I have to change a default or something like this?**

I found nothing to this problem.

My wish endresult is to see 2 ssh terminals next to each other and not to have to switch tabs all the time. Is this possible?`

Answer (score 1):

> ...instead of a second remote shell.

My workaround is to simply ssh the remote again in that local shell.

Answer (score 0):

Open ssh shells. Right click on them and select "Move to Editor" then you can put them one for one on the other screen and place each window as you like.

Answer (score 0):

just login again using `ssh root@your_ip`